# Fill jQuery or ajax by PHP var

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to fill jQuery variable by PHP???

I mean something like this:

`<?php

$string_php = "50%";

?>`

And with "$string" variable I want to fill jQuery:

`var jquery_string = "$string_php";

$('.bar1').animate({'height':'jquery_string'},500);`

The code above is only idea how I would like to be working

Comment: php can output anything really, so just output php where you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure

```
var jquery_string = "<?php echo $string_php;?>";
```

Since PHP is processed first on the server and the result is then sent to the user's browser, this is easy, and often done.

The above code would result in:

```
var jquery_string = "50%";
```

You would, however want to modify your second line, removing the quotes from the variable so it was:

```
$('.bar1').animate({'height':jquery_string},500);
```

since keeping the quotes around `jquery_string` would make force it to be interpreted as a string whereas you want a variable.

The end result would be the equivalent of:

```
$('.bar1').animate({'height':'50%'},500);
```

Comment: Will fail as a general approach when double quotes are present.

Comment: So escape them or mix with single quotes. Your example is hypothetical and not related to the OP's question.

Comment: My example, is not only correct and a good practice, it is also the most general and should be the general approach when outputting strings directly in Javascript from PHP. As I said to Blaster, The OP's main question is: *Is it possible to fill jQuery variable by PHP???*, not *is it possible to fill a JQuery animation parameter by PHP*.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** but with **php tags** `<?php ?>` (so that php knows its code):

```
var jquery_string = "<?php echo $string_php;?>";
$('.bar1').animate({'height':jquery_string}, 500); // no quotes for variables
```

It is possible because PHP (server-side) runs before jQuery (client-side). The page first goes to server and server returns the response (php code is parsed there) to the browser.

Comment: What if there are double quotes IN the string? Wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

For simple variables, just do as the users said.

F.ex. `var jquery_string = "<?php echo $string_php;?>";` (taken from @Blaster's solution).
In other words:

> The most simple solution is to output a php variable that we intend to use as **string literal** via echo anywhere we define the variable.

But: a correct approach would be that everytime we use a serverside variable **as a Javascript string**, it should be encoded, because the above solutions would fail when double quotes are present. Here `json_encode` may come handy.

```
var jquery_string = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
```

---

### Code example

We want Javascript alert the string `"Hey", dude!`

```
$string = "\"Hey\", dude!";
echo "alert(\"" . $string . "\");";
```

results in:

```
alert(""Hey", dude!"); <--- will give Javascript error
```

Instead:

```
 echo "alert(" . json_encode($string) . ");";
```

results in:

```
alert("\"Hey\", dude!"); <---- correct JS code
```

Comment: I didn't down vote  but his `animate` function needs `50%` value, no need to json_encode it or in other words, his animation will not work.

Comment: @Blaster The general question was: **Is it possible to fill jQuery variable by PHP?**, with a particular example given, not **Is it possible to fill a JQuery animation parameter?** There was no clue that the "50%" was a strict example or just a general example. So I gave the most complete answer.
I never complain about downvotes, *ever*, but these seem idiocy to me. If my code is off-topic or conceptually *wrong*, instead, I'll take it as a lesson without complaints.

Comment: Thinking about it, I may have been a bit rude @Blaster, if so I am sorry with you and the other guy. I'm open to discussion about the matter if necessary.